# How to programatically disable all purposes for an SSL CA Root Certificate in C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, ssl-certificate, x509

Since Thawte (and several other CA's) transitioned from 1024-bit roots to new, more secure 2048-bit roots, there have been complications in the verification of certain SSL certificates such as the Thawte wildcard certificate since it contains the "thawte Primary Root CA" in its certificate chain.

This has resulted in certain browsers not being able to verify the certificate when installed in Windows.
The manual resolution can be found at http://www.tbs-certificats.com/FAQ/en/608.html.

The challenge here is that for certain hosting environments such as Microsoft Azure, where a website's underlying OS instance can be changed at any time, such a manual change will be useless since the root certificate will continuously be "refreshed" to its original "erroneous" state.

Some articles have pointed me in the right direction to make this change programmatically (
http://en-us.sysadmins.lv/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=332991f0-bfed-4143-9eea-f521167d287c&ID=69 and http://forums.asp.net/t/1531893.aspx/1).
It seems the only way to do this is using the CryptoAPI.

The following is my console app code to try and achieve this:

```
class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(
            IntPtr pCertContext,
            uint dwPropId,
            Byte[] pvData,
            ref uint pcbData
        );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CertSetEnhancedKeyUsage(
            IntPtr pCertContext,
            IntPtr pUsage
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "344ed55720d5edec49f42fce37db2b6d", false)[0];

                if (!cert.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    uint pcbData = 0;
                    // if the function returns True, then certificate purposes are either disabled or constrained
                    // otherwise (False) valid purposes are determined by certificate's EKU
                    if (CertGetCertificateContextProperty(cert.Handle, 0x9, null, ref pcbData))
                    {
                        // create a buffer for ASN.1 encoded byte array
                        byte[] pvData = new byte[pcbData];
                        // call the function again to write actual data
                        CertGetCertificateContextProperty(cert.Handle, 0x9, pvData, ref pcbData);
                        // instantiate AsnEncodedData object with ASN.1 encoded byte array
                        AsnEncodedData asn = new AsnEncodedData("", pvData);
                        // instaintiate X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension to retrieve OIDs in a readable form
                        X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension eku = new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(asn, false);
                        // if none OIDs are defined, then all certificate purposes are explicitly diabled in the properties
                        if (eku.EnhancedKeyUsages.Count == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("All purposes for this certificate are explicitly disabled.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // constrained OIDs
                            OidCollection keyUsages = eku.EnhancedKeyUsages;

                            // disable all purposes by emptying EnhancedKeyUsages
                            IntPtr pUsage = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0);
                            CertSetEnhancedKeyUsage(cert.Handle, pUsage);                           
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Valid purposes are determined by the certificate EKU extension.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("An attempt was made to access an uninitialized object.");
                }

                store.Close();
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Information could not be written out for this certificate.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

The result of this seems positive, since on the 2nd run of the console app all purposes seem disabled, the caveat however is that the changes are not visible in certmgr.msc, purposes still look enabled.

Also, when the above code is placed in Global.asax of my MVC website, it seems to have no effect whatsoever on the certificate.

So my question is 2 fold:

1. How do I disable all purposes for a certificate resulting in the Windows certificate snap-in displaying the certificate change?
2. How do I achieve this persistently in ASP.NET?

Comment: If your code really tries to change the Extended Key Usages extension, then this most likely breaks the signature of the certificate. Thus, the certificate wont be verifiable anymore in its certificate chain.

Comment: @mkl, thank you. How do you then propose I achieve the certificate modification automatically, since this is what the Thawte support team has advised me to change in the root cert?

Comment: Please supply your public certificate and what thawte exactly purposes.

Comment: public certificate at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/174a5caa180a04bf2c3b

Comment: This article better explains the requirement from Thawte for any certificates issued after 27 June 2010: http://ripley.za.net/2010/09/howto/it_howto/ssl-web-server-or-wildcard-certificate-issued-after-june-26-2010-not-trusted-after-installation-on-microsoft-iis

Comment: And just to be sure, *Thawte support team has advised to change the root cert* on the Azure hosting machine your web app currently runs on? Is it to be expected that you are allowed to do such changes, i.e. manipulating the certificate stores, on such hosting platforms?

Comment: Obviously, Thawte support on IIS issues is generic to Windows Server. For those who are unfamiliar with Azure cloud services, websites / services can be referenced in a VS cloud project, packaged and published directly to the Azure cloud either from VS directly or through the Azure portal. The deployed application is then "installed" on its own virtual Windows instance.

Comment: The Azure OS hypervisor can at any time replace an instance with a fresh instance and a new installation of the application (deployed from the original package). Since one is able to RDP directly into the virtual server and make changes to the OS like any server, I have managed to manually change the certificate properties as per the manual instructions above. Given that this is a dedicated instance, one can make what ever changes to the OS one wishes.

Comment: Hence I feel this gives me license to make the underlying certificate changes programmatically, if I am able to and it would be irresponsible not to since these changes can be "reset" by Azure at any time.

Comment: @ashleybrener If you are deploying to an Azure Cloud Service, then in your service configuration file for the Web Role, you can specify the "Disallowed" store name for a given certificate to tell the underlying VM to disregard it. I guess that is what you are looking for?